# Dynamically map JSON to a SQL table, adding and naming columns based on JSON keys

Tags: postgresql, graphql, jsonb

I am using the http extension in Postgresql, making a request, and getting a list of jsonb [{keys, values}] in a single column `details` as a response.

It seems like there should be an easy way to create a new table from the keys and values.

Here is the request:

```sql
WITH sport_markets_api AS (
    SELECT ((CONTENT::jsonb ->> 'data')::jsonb ->> 'sportMarkets')::jsonb AS details 
    FROM http_post(
        'https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/',
        '{"query": "{sportMarkets(first:2,skip:0,orderBy:timestamp,orderDirection:desc){id,timestamp,address,gameId,maturityDate,tags,isOpen,isResolved,isCanceled,finalResult,homeTeam,awayTeam }}"}'::text,
        'application/json'))
```

I tried:

```sql
SELECT col.*
FROM sport_markets_api,
     jsonb_to_recordset(details) AS col(id TEXT,tags TEXT,total INT)
```

and this works...however I am looking for an easier way to create columns from `jsonb_object_keys()`. It can be rather tedious when calling different APIs with > 10 columns.

Example response:

```
{"data":
  {"sportMarkets":
     [   {"id": "9f4a2", "tags": ["9006"], "total": null, "betType": "10001", "awayOdds": "203707333464004703", "awayTeam": "Ottawa Senators", "drawOdds": "0", "homeOdds": "796292666535995296", "homeTeam": "Los Angeles Kings", "isPaused": false},
         {"id": "9f4a3", "tags": ["9007","9005"], "total": null, "betType": "10002", "awayOdds": "'||(random()*203707333464004703)::bigint||'", "awayTeam": "Nebraska Governors", "drawOdds": "0", "homeOdds": "'||(random()*796292666535995296)::bigint||'", "homeTeam": "Los Santos Bloods", "isPaused": true},
         {"id": "9f4a2", "tags": ["9006"], "total": 5, "betType": "10003", "awayOdds": "'||(random()*203707333464004703)::bigint||'", "awayTeam": "Utah Saints", "drawOdds": "0", "homeOdds": "'||(random()*796292666535995296)::bigint||'", "homeTeam": "Burger King Sodas", "isPaused": false}
     ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid specifying field types and names in your records when calling [`jsonb_to_recordset()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.12.1.2.1), before you pass that to [`create table as`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html), then there's also [`jsonb_populate_recordset()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.10.1.2.1) in case you have that structure already defined somewhere, as `table` or a [`type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/CCMjcKma)

```sql
CREATE TYPE my_type AS (id text, tags text[], total int, "betType" text, 
                        "awayOdds" bigint, "awayTeam" text, "drawOdds" bigint, 
                        "homeOdds" bigint, "homeTeam" text, "isPaused" boolean);

CREATE TABLE my_table2 AS
WITH sport_markets_api AS (
    SELECT ((CONTENT::jsonb ->> 'data')::jsonb ->> 'sportMarkets')::jsonb AS details 
    FROM http_post(
        'https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/',
        '{"query": "{sportMarkets(first:2,skip:0,orderBy:timestamp,orderDirection:desc){id,timestamp,address,gameId,maturityDate,tags,isOpen,isResolved,isCanceled,finalResult,homeTeam,awayTeam }}"}'::text,
        'application/json'))
SELECT r.*
FROM sport_markets_api,
     jsonb_populate_recordset(null::my_type,details) as r;

SELECT * FROM my_table2;
```

| id | tags | total | betType | awayOdds | awayTeam | drawOdds | homeOdds | homeTeam | isPaused |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9f4a2 | {9006} | *null* | 10001 | 203707333464004703 | Ottawa Senators | 0 | 796292666535995296 | Los Angeles Kings | f |
| 9f4a3 | {9007,9005} | *null* | 10002 | 7248793422157497 | Nebraska Governors | 0 | 367914422982970560 | Los Santos Bloods | t |
| 9f4a2 | {9006} | 5 | 10003 | 80554882934156496 | Utah Saints | 0 | 419810059157643712 | Burger King Sodas | f |

In case you don't already have a table or a type to map those to, you can avoid mapping out each `json` individually, by hand: list pairs of field names and values with `jsonb_each_text()`, then pivot that with [`crosstab`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#TABLEFUNC-FUNCTIONS-CROSSTAB-TEXT), kind of like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75733913/5298879):

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
DO $f$
BEGIN
CREATE TEMP TABLE sport_markets_api ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT ((CONTENT::jsonb ->> 'data')::jsonb ->> 'sportMarkets')::jsonb AS details 
FROM http_post( 'https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/'
               ,'{"query": "{sportMarkets(first:2,skip:0,orderBy:timestamp,orderDirection:desc){id,timestamp,address,gameId,maturityDate,tags,isOpen,isResolved,isCanceled,finalResult,homeTeam,awayTeam }}"}'::text
               ,'application/json');
EXECUTE FORMAT(
  $dyn_sql$
    CREATE TABLE map_json_dynamically AS
    SELECT *
    FROM crosstab(
        $crst$
        SELECT element_num, field_name, val
        FROM sport_markets_api,
             jsonb_array_elements(details)
             with ordinality e(element_,element_num),
             jsonb_each_text(element_)x(field_name, val)
        $crst$
      , 'SELECT jsonb_object_keys(example)field_name
         FROM (SELECT details[0] AS example 
               FROM sport_markets_api LIMIT 1)_'
    ) AS ct (element_num int, %1$s) 
  $dyn_sql$
  , (SELECT string_agg(format('%I text',field_name),', ')
     FROM (SELECT jsonb_object_keys(example)field_name
           FROM (SELECT details[0] AS example 
                 FROM sport_markets_api LIMIT 1)_)_));

END $f$;
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM map_json_dynamically;
```

| element_num | id | tags | total | betType | awayOdds | awayTeam | drawOdds | homeOdds | homeTeam | isPaused |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9f4a2 | ["9006"] | *null* | 10001 | 203707333464004703 | Ottawa Senators | 0 | 796292666535995296 | Los Angeles Kings | false |
| 2 | 9f4a3 | ["9007", "9005"] | *null* | 10002 | 111916761610270288 | Nebraska Governors | 0 | 231034811655113152 | Los Santos Bloods | true |
| 3 | 9f4a2 | ["9006"] | 5 | 10003 | 34666840126829848 | Utah Saints | 0 | 156478668264038336 | Burger King Sodas | false |

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear.  The response would be 13 columns ...the goal would be to have the resulting key column's distinct values as their own column.

Comment: Can you show a sample/mock json before and a table record after the mapping you're aiming to do?

Comment: This is one row of ```  SELECT jsonb_array_elements(details) from sports_market_api  ```         {"id": "9f4a2", "tags": ["9006"], "total": null, "betType": "10001", "awayOdds": "203707333464004703", "awayTeam": "Ottawa Senators", "drawOdds": "0", "homeOdds": "796292666535995296", "homeTeam": "Los Angeles Kings", "isPaused": false}   AND columns would be id, tags, total, betType etc.  There are thousands of rows.

Comment: Second option above, then. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/wpqroSwL)

Comment: @JohnSweeney I read [your last update](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78125638/4) pretty late: mapping different json structures *dynamically* is a whole different, ugly thing, but it's possible. Example added

Comment: Thanks @Zegarek !! lots of things in there I had no clue about... I voted your answer up but I don't have enough street cred yet for it to show.

Comment: @JohnSweeney No worries. Your rep is visible right in the new questions queue: some people give those with <15 points a wide berth because of the missing [vote-up privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), meaning that OP can at best accept the answer, but they cannot vote it up, plus the thread will attract less users who can and potentially would. If someone does answer, they know the stakes - I do and I just don't mind.

Comment: Interesting yeah I am still new to this.  I don't have an option to accept the answer either...is that because there is only 1 to choose from ?